# Where to find a configuration file for SourceInsight?

Tags: editor, source-insight

Where to find a configuration file for SourceInsight?

The default configuration of the software makes the
code even unreadable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here are Source Insight configuration files (.clf) for some programming languages which I think did not come with Source Insight.

Adding the link I think I forgot:

See "Languages" at http://www.sourceinsight.com/public/. I'm having trouble accessing it just now, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Where exactly are these config files?  Did you forget a link?